# How to push Struct with a mapping to an array?

Tags: solidity, mapping, struct

I have a struct called Meeting that contains an array of addresses. I want to check that the address doesn't exist before it RSVPs to a meeting, so I created a mapping called hasRSVPed. (I could loop through the array of addresses, but that is inefficient).

I am trying to push the created Meeting into an array of Meetings, but how do I do that if the Meeting contains a mapping?

I get the following error when I tried this

```
TypeError: Uninitialized mapping. Mappings cannot be created dynamically, you have to assign them from a state variable.
```

```
 struct Meeting {
        address meeting_creator;
        uint256 meetingID;
        string name;
        string description;
        uint256 start_date;
        uint256 end_date;
        uint256 max_tickets;
        uint256 ticket_price;
        uint256 current_tickets_sold;
        address[] attendees;
        mapping(address => bool) hasRSVPed;

    }

Meeting[] public meetingArray;

function create_meeting(string memory _name, string memory _description, uint _startTime, uint _endTime, uint _maxTickets,
    uint256 _ticketPrice) public returns (uint256 meetingID) {

        address[] memory adr;
        mapping(address => bool) memory RSVPed;

        totalMeetings += 1;
        meetingID = totalMeetings;

        meetingArray.push(Meeting(msg.sender, meetingID, _name, _description, _startTime, _endTime, _maxTickets, _ticketPrice, 0, adr, RSVPed));

        Meeting storage m = meetings[totalMeetings];
        m.meeting_creator = msg.sender;
        m.meetingID = meetingID;
        m.name = _name;
        m.description = _description;
        m.start_date = _startTime;
        m.end_date = _endTime;
        m.max_tickets = _maxTickets;
        m.ticket_price = _ticketPrice;
        m.current_tickets_sold = 0;
        m.attendees = adr;
        m.hasRSVPed = RSVPed;
}
```

Comment: Please, can you explain better your smart contract purpose?

Comment: Sure, I'm trying to create a decentralized EventBrite where one can create Meetings and attend meetings by staking coins

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to push a dynamic mapping to an array. As far as I can tell, this may not be possible because array is itself dynamic in nature in Solidity. So, pushing a mapping whose size cannot be determined at first, solidity cannot calculate the storage slot in EVM properly. Or, it could incur a gas cost thats too high.

So I would suggest using a mapping(uint => bool) hasRSVPed instead which tracks if a meeting with a unique id has been RSVPed or not.

I have a small snippet of the code used by you with implementation of the code I pointed out.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
contract meeting {
    uint totalMeetings;
    struct Meeting {
        address meeting_creator;
    }
    mapping(uint => bool) hasRSVPed;
    mapping(uint => Meeting) meetings;

Meeting[] private meetingArray;

function create_meeting(string memory _name, string memory _description, uint _startTime, uint _endTime, uint _maxTickets,
    uint256 _ticketPrice) public returns (uint256 meetingID) {

        address[] memory adr;
        totalMeetings += 1;
        Meeting storage m = meetings[totalMeetings];
        m.meeting_creator = msg.sender;
        hasRSVPed[totalMeetings] = true;
}
```

Comment: I see, but I want multiple addresses to 'RSVP' to a meeting, hence why I put an array of addresses inside the Meeting struct. How do I use a mapping to check that the address is not in the array of a specific Meeting?

Comment: try this then:
mapping(address => mapping(uint => bool));

So, addresses are mapped to meetings. So that address and its meeting id is mapped to bool